# Use PyCharm (or any Windows IDE) to run SageMath scripts

Tags: pycharm, sage

How do I configure PyCharm so I can edit and run Sage scripts?

I am using SageMath 8 on Windows.

I thought I could maybe start PyCharm from the Sage shell, but after doing so I couldn't select Sage's python as interpreter, located at `C:\Program Files\SageMath 8.0\runtime\opt\sagemath-8.0\local\bin\python.exe` because it gave me `Invalid Python SDK`.

[Edit] I'm actually just searching for any IDE from which I can hit a 'run' button to run my Sage scripts.

Comment: Also asked, and answered, at

- [Ask Sage question 39742: Make PyCharm recognise the Sage Python interpreter](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/39742/make-pycharm-recognise-the-sage-python-interpreter/)

Comment: And the follow-up question after the one @SamuelLelièvre linked to (thanks): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sage-devel/iKQY5Em-QpY/JBe0YS9oCQAJ;context-place=forum/sage-devel
Unfortunately I can't add the complete answer since the issue is still not completely resolved (I think the next thing I'd try is using vim).